# OpenERP Magento integration failed when try to import websites

Tags: magento, python-2.7, magento-1.7, integration, odoo

I've installed OpenERP 7 and Magento 1.7. One of my tasks is deploying a connector between them. I've installed the Openlabs OpenERP connector to Magento, and install magento-integration module to OpenERP from here (https://github.com/openlabs/magento-integration).

The 'Test Connection' function works fine. After I click the `Import Websites`, the stack trace shown in the popup:

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
...
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 861, in _get_id
raise ValueError('No such external ID currently defined in the system: %s.%s' % (module, xml_id))
ValueError: No such external ID currently defined in the system: magento_integration.instance_website_tree_view
```

I am not familiar with OpenERP (and python), so  my question is what is the `ValueError: No such external ID currently defined in the system: magento_integration.instance_website_tree_view`, and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody? Is this such a special problem?

Comment: possibly you should report this problem at repository it self on :https://github.com/openlabs/magento-integration

Answer (score 0):

This Error Shown because in the module magento_integration no Xml id-instance_website_tree_view is defined

but some where it is used as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem and the only solution I could find was to rename the module directory from `magento_integration-develop/` to `magento_integration/`. I don't know if this fixes all of these issues but it no longer returns that error and it's from the developer on github.

https://github.com/openlabs/magento_integration/issues/87